# Pygame not finding image folder when in subdirectory

Tags: python, pygame

I've been refactoring my game so that some files are placed in a subdirectory called /lib/ [File Structure below].

Two of these files are a python file called media.py, and a folder just called media. Media.py is pretty much a couple lines of this code:

```
blue = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('media', 'blue.png')).convert_alpha()
```

When I placed media.py and the media folder in lib and run media.py, It works perfectly fine, no errors.

But when I run Main.py, and It tries to call and import Media.py, It raises an error saying that media.py cannot find any file within the media folder, even when they are in the same subdirectory, and worked perfectly fine before.

I've tried to use the full file path and os.path.abspath but they dont work either, and raise the same errors.

Here is the area that raises the error in main.py:

```
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
import media
```

Here is my file structure:

```
Game
|
| - Lib
|   |
|   | - Media
|   |       |
|   |       blue.png, along with many other images
|   Media.py
|   |
|   Fetch.py
|   |
|   gamewide.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code depends on the start directory.

To be independent from that you could use the fact that the image file is in the same directory as `Media.py` and the dir name of `__file__` object

Then:

```
blue = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Media','blue.png')).convert_alpha()
```

will do the trick