# How do I open an image from a different directory in python for pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, pygame, sprite

I am trying to open a png image that is not in the same folder as python. I dont know what to do even though I set the pathway.

I don't know what to do at all

```py
image1 = pygame.image.load('Libraries\Pictures\pixel6.png')
image1 = pygame.transform.scale(image1, (1000, 500))
```

It says that the image cannot be opened

Comment: Either a possible duplicate of [Pygame not finding image folder when in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577034/pygame-not-finding-image-folder-when-in-subdirectory), or have you tried adding an `.\ ` to your file path?

Comment: What is the working directory? `import os` `os.getcwd()`

Comment: If you want to be completely sure, try entering the [absolute path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337443/what-is-a-full-path-name) of the image. something like this: ```C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python Programs\test_python.py```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11454726/dan) pointed out, entering the absolute path of the image could definitely work.

Alternatively, you can navigate up the folder hierarchy from the local directory (the directory in which your code file is stored). Let's say that your filesystem appears as follows:

- You have a directory, `Stuff`, that contains two folders, `Python` and `Image`.
- The `Python` folder contains your code, `test_python.py`.
- The `Image` folder contains your image, `pixel16.png`.

Then, the command would look something like this:

```
image1 = pygame.image.load("../Image/pixel16.png")
```

Because the `..` takes you up the file tree from the `Python` folder to the `Stuff` folder (because when in a given directory, the `..` command takes you to the parent directory), and from there the rest of the path navigates you to the image that you're hoping to access.

Hope this helps!